# Add total in magento custom module grid footer

Tags: magento, grid, magento-1.7

i have added sales order grid in my custom module.and also get footer total row in the grid. but the problem is when i add 'adult' column in the total it display nothing.for `adult,child,total` i m using renderer to get row data from order.so how to get total for `adult,child,total` at the footer.

i have used below code to display footer totals in grid.php

```
protected $_countTotals = true;
   public function getTotals()
    {
        $totals = new Varien_Object();
        $fields = array(
            'base_grand_total' => 0,
            'adult'=>0,
         //actual column index, see _prepareColumns()
        );
        foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
            foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
                $fields[$field]+=$item->getData($field);
            }
        }
        //First column in the grid
        $fields['increment_id'] = 'Totals';
        $totals->setData($fields);
        return $totals;
    }
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: pls check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/how-to-add-a-total-row-in-a-magento-grid

Comment: ha ha @Freedom you sorry i didn't saw your profile

Comment: yes @KeyurShah but you had helped me to get that done.Thanks for that but now problem is adult column total is not displayed.because that uses rendere for get row data i m not sure but may be.then how this custom column add to row total?

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to the grid.php

```
public function getReport($from, $to) {
        if ($from == '') {
            $from = $this->getFilter('report_from');
        }
        if ($to == '') {
            $to = $this->getFilter('report_to');
        }
        $totalObj = Mage::getModel('reports/totals');
        $totals = $totalObj->countTotals($this, $from, $to);
        $this->setTotals($totals);
        $this->addGrandTotals($totals);
        return $this->getCollection()->getReport($from, $to);
    }
```

and also in adding column add `'total' => 'sum'` as below (I think you made this but once verify it properly):

```
$this->addColumn('item_id', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Item ID'),
            'align' => 'right',
            'index' => 'item_id',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'total' => 'sum',
        ));
```

Comment: have add this function and total=>sum in the grid.php but nothing happen.

Comment: got the same value: $0, did you get this fixed using render?